# Why vertices of directed acyclic graph are considered strongly-connected components?

Tags: graphs

Well the title pretty much says it all, I've heard our professor saying that the smallest strongly-connected components in DAG (directed acyclic graph) are its vertices. Sadly I was unable to ask him for explanation and now this is stuck in my head ever since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with the definition of [Strongly Connected Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in graph theory.

> A graph to be said to be Strongly Connected if every vertex is
>   reachable from every other vertex.

The smallest possible graph of any type consists of a single vertex.
Since that vertex can reach itself (since it is itself), the graph therefore meets the criteria, and can be considered *Strongly Connected*.

In this image, the nodes at the bottom right, and the top middle are examples of smallest possible strongly connected components: [image]

Comment: But isnt directed *acyclic* graphs graphs without cycle or cycle of one vertex is not considered cycle? I admit I am really bad at graphs and graph theory..

Comment: I added an image that should help. A DAG can have many components which themselves are not acyclic, like in the image. But once you leave a component, you cant go back to the previous component, thus acyclic. But yes, a vertex is not considered a cycle on its own. to have a cycle you have to traverse an edge.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks a lot, I will try to topologically sort it now :)